# URL quoting characters inside the value of a hidden input

Tags: html, forms, xhtml, input

Say I have a form whose action target expects a value with spaces in it. If I were typing the request out manually as a URL, I'd use `%20` to escape the spaces. If I use a hidden input for this parameter instead, should the value contain the spaces themselves, or the URL quoted `%20` sequences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spaces!  Let the browser HTML-escape the values for you on form submission.

Comment: Turns out they should be escaped with `+` anyway, not `%20`!